# Interpret the Pig series

Tags: code-golf, string, random, file-system

Given an input of a [Pig](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Pig),
[SickPig](http://esolangs.org/wiki/SickPig),
[DeadPig](http://esolangs.org/wiki/DeadPig),
[QuinePig](http://esolangs.org/wiki/QuinePig), or
[DeafPig](http://esolangs.org/wiki/DeafPig) program, choose one of those
"languages" randomly and interpret the input as that "language."

First, randomly choose between one of the five members of the "Pig series":

- ### Pig

  If the choice was Pig, mimic the [reference
  interpreter](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Pig) by doing the following:

  - Find the first occurrence of the word `PIG` in the input
    (case-sensitive).
  - If the word `PIG` does not appear in the input, output the message
    `File must contain the string 'PIG'.` and exit.
  - Otherwise, split the input string on the first occurrence of `PIG`.
    Output the text after the first occurrence of `PIG` to a file with a
    filename of the text before `PIG`.

    `PIG` may be contained in the text to be output (so, an input of
    `fooPIGbarPIGbaz` should output `barPIGbaz` to a file called `foo`).

  Note that the reference interpreter takes input via a command line argument
  that specifies a filename to read from. However, your submission may take input in
  any of the standard methods accepted on PPCG.
- ### SickPig

  If the choice was SickPig, follow the same instructions as Pig. However,
  instead of writing the text after `PIG` to the file, choose randomly from
  the following list

  ```
  GRUNT
  MOAN
  OINK
  BURP
  GROAN
  WHINE
  ```

  and output that to the file instead. This random choice must be
  independent of the previous choice (so, an output of `GRUNT` should
  have a 1/5 * 1/6 = 1/30 chance overall).
- ### DeadPig

  DeadPig is like SickPig, but it always outputs the following string instead
  of randomly choosing a string:

  ```
  Your pig has unfortunately died. Please try again.
  ```
- ### QuinePig

  QuinePig is like Pig, but instead of writing the text after `PIG` to the
  file, it instead writes the entire input to the file (so, an input of
  `fooPIGbarPIGbaz` should output `fooPIGbarPIGbaz` to a file called `foo`).
- ### DeafPig

  If the choice was DeafPig, do nothing. (The pig is deaf... what do you
  expect?)

Miscellaneous rules:

- "Random" means each choice should be roughly equally likely (so, choosing Pig 90% of the time and the other variants only 2.5% of the time is invalid).
- You may assume that the requested filenames will always be valid for your
  file system (but they may contain spaces, etc.).
- For all the variants of Pig, your code may optionally output a single
  trailing newline to the file as well.
- Since this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest code in bytes will win.

Comment: +1 what do you expect?

Comment: Does the random choice have to be perfectly uniform or is modding 32768 acceptable?

Comment: @Dennis *Perfect* uniformity is not necessary, but each choice must have a roughly equal probability (so mod a big number is okay).

Comment: Woah... I wrote that Pig interpreter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Pyth - 157 bytes

Will be doing string compression.

```
?}J"PIG"z?=GO[jJtKczJOc"GRUNT MOAN OINK BURP GROAN WHINE"d"Your pig has unfortunately died. Please try again."z0).wGhK.q"File must contain the string 'PIG'."
```

Doesn't work online cuz of file I/O, but try it outputting `[content, filename]` to stdio [here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%3F%7DJ%22PIG%22z%3F%3DGO%5BjJtKczJOc%22GRUNT+MOAN+OINK+BURP+GROAN+WHINE%22d%22Your+pig+has+unfortunately+died.+Please+try+again.%22z0%29%5BGhK%29.q%22File+must+contain+the+string+%27PIG%27.%22&input=fooPIGbarPIGbaz&debug=0).

Answer (score 6):

## Bash, <s>251</s> 246 bytes

```
r=$RANDOM
((r%5<4))||exit
[[ $1 =~ PIG ]]||(echo "File must contain the string 'PIG'.";exit)
s=(GRUNT MOAN OINK BURP GROAN WHINE)
m=("${1#*PIG}" ${s[r%6]}
"Your pig has unfortunately died. Please try again." "$1")
echo -n "${m[r%5]}">"${1%%PIG*}"
```

This would be a lot shorter if deaf pigs could at least read...

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, <s>296</s> <s>286</s> 278 bytes

```
def g(p):
 import random;f=random.randint;r=f(0,4);i=p.find("PIG")
 if r:
    if i+1:open(p[:i],"w").write([0,p[i+3:],["GRUNT","MOAN","OINK","BURP","GROAN","WHINE"][f(0,5)],"Your pig has unfortunately died. Please try again.",p][r])
    else:print"File must contain the string 'PIG'."
```

*The last two lines start with a tab, instead of the rendered 4 spaces.*

Takes input program as function argument.

Comment: Hello, when I count the bytes in your submission, I get 317. How are you counting the bytes?

Comment: @Ogaday The four spaces preceding the last two lines are actually tab characters. (Stack Exchange replaces tabs with spaces within code blocks, though.)

Comment: @Doorknob Ah, ok! That would be it. I wondered why the spaces hadn't been golfed out.

Comment: There should be a period after `'PIG'`.

Comment: @LegionMammal978 Thanks for the hint, complety missed that.

Answer (score 2):

### Batch, <s>409</s> <s>406</s> 405 bytes

```
@echo off
set/ar=%random%%%5
if 0==%r% exit/b
set p=x%1
set q=%p:*PIG=%
if %q%==%p% echo File must contain the string 'PIG'.&exit/b
set p=%1
call set p=%%p:PIG%q%=%%
goto %r%
:1
echo %q%>%p%
exit/b
:2
for %%a in (GRUNT.0 MOAN.1 OINK.2 BURP.3 GROAN.4 WHINE.5)do if %%~xa==.%time:~6,1% echo %%~na
exit/b
:3
echo Your pig has unfortunately died. Please try again.>%p%
exit/b
:4
echo %1>%p%
```

Sadly `%p:*PIG=%` fails if p is blank, thus the `x%1` hack. `call set` is a nice way to avoid enabledelayedexpansion that I found on Stack Overflow; while the `%%~xa==.` was a flash of inspiration on my part.

Edit: Saved 3 bytes thanks to @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ. Saved 1 byte thanks to @EʀɪᴋᴛʜᴇGᴏʟғᴇʀ.

Comment: Why `@echo on`? Isn't that implicitly done? Perhaps you meant `@echo off`?

Comment: Also, for generating a random number, `SET/A r=%RANDOM%%%5` is shorter.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Ugh, I meant `@echo off` but I had been debugging... also thanks for the %RANDOM% tip, I hadn't heard of that one.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Sadly the `%RANDOM%` version requires me to use an extra `set /a` which ends up being 10 bytes longer.

Comment: But you're already using `set/a`...?

Comment: Not the second time.